# Windows 10 PC keeps Freezing

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze

My computer keeps freezing and I'm struggling to find the cause of the issue. I have tried replacing the RAM. De-fragmenting, disk clean ups, windows updates, disabling automatic updates.

It either freezes with no message or occasionally displays the CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT error.

The easiest way I can replicate the error is video editing or playing a game and turning settings up to high. I can also replicate the error when running a full antivirus scan with AVG (error still occurs when I uninstall it)

**Updates**

19/01/2016 - I have tried a repair install and the issue still persists

The Specs of the PC are below:

```
Operating System: Windows 10
Mother board: Asus maximus vi impact
Processor: intel i7 4790k
Processor Cooler: Corsair H80i 
Graphics Card: MSI GeForce GTX 770 2GB PCI-E 3.0
Power: Corsair 650W CS650M CSM Semi-Modular
Ram: Corsair Vengeance Pro Series 16GB (2x8GB) DDR3 2400Mhz 
Main hard Drive: Samsung 840 EVO 500GB
Other Drive: Seagate 3TB 3.5 inch 7200RPM
```

Running MiniToolBox.exe I get the following event log error:

MiniToolBox by Farbar  Version: 02-11-2015
Ran by difurious (administrator) on 14-01-2016 at 21:57:45
Running from "E:\Downloads"
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro  (X64)
Model: All Series Manufacturer: ASUS
Boot Mode: Normal

---

========================= Event log errors: ===============================

## Application errors:

Error: (01/14/2016 09:22:06 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell) (User: difurious)
Description: Activation of application Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI failed with error: -2144927141 See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

Error: (01/14/2016 09:19:44 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell) (User: difurious)
Description: Activation of application Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI failed with error: -2144927141 See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

Error: (01/14/2016 07:42:35 PM) (Source: Application Error) (User: )
Description: Faulting application name: SystemSettings.exe, version: 10.0.10240.16384, time stamp: 0x559f39ae
Faulting module name: MusUpdateHandlers.dll, version: 10.0.10240.16590, time stamp: 0x563ad6f2
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000002c7a8
Faulting process ID: 0x22a0
Faulting application start time: 0xSystemSettings.exe0
Faulting application path: SystemSettings.exe1
Faulting module path: SystemSettings.exe2
Report ID: SystemSettings.exe3
Faulting package full name: SystemSettings.exe4
Faulting package-relative application ID: SystemSettings.exe5

Error: (01/14/2016 07:09:48 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2) (User: )
Description: Cryptographic Services failed while processing the OnIdentity() call in the System Writer Object.

Details:
AddLegacyDriverFiles: Unable to back up image of binary Microsoft Link-Layer Discovery Protocol.

System Error:
Access is denied.
.

Error: (01/14/2016 06:47:23 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell) (User: difurious)
Description: Activation of application Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI failed with error: -2147024865 See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

Error: (01/14/2016 06:47:23 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell) (User: difurious)
Description: Activation of application Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI failed with error: -2144927141 See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

Error: (01/11/2016 10:25:41 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell) (User: difurious)
Description: Activation of application Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI failed with error: -2144927141 See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

Error: (01/11/2016 10:25:41 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell) (User: difurious)
Description: Activation of application Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy!App failed with error: -2144927141 See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

Error: (01/10/2016 10:14:27 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell) (User: difurious)
Description: Activation of application Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI failed with error: -2144927141 See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

## System errors:

Error: (01/14/2016 09:49:23 PM) (Source: DCOM) (User: NT AUTHORITY)
Description: {784E29F4-5EBE-4279-9948-1E8FE941646D}

Error: (01/14/2016 09:44:12 PM) (Source: EventLog) (User: )
Description: The previous system shutdown at 9:39:23 PM on ‎1/‎14/‎2016 was unexpected.

Error: (01/14/2016 09:39:24 PM) (Source: BugCheck) (User: )
Description: 0x00000101 (0x0000000000000018, 0x0000000000000000, 0xffffd0010831f180, 0x0000000000000004)C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP

Error: (01/14/2016 09:39:24 PM) (Source: BugCheck) (User: )
Description:

Error: (01/14/2016 09:39:23 PM) (Source: EventLog) (User: )
Description: The previous system shutdown at 9:29:09 PM on ‎1/‎14/‎2016 was unexpected.

Error: (01/14/2016 09:32:17 PM) (Source: DCOM) (User: NT AUTHORITY)
Description: {784E29F4-5EBE-4279-9948-1E8FE941646D}

Error: (01/14/2016 09:28:13 PM) (Source: DCOM) (User: difurious)
Description: 1084WSearchUnavailable{7D096C5F-AC08-4F1F-BEB7-5C22C517CE39}

Error: (01/14/2016 09:28:12 PM) (Source: DCOM) (User: difurious)
Description: 1084WSearchUnavailable{7D096C5F-AC08-4F1F-BEB7-5C22C517CE39}

Error: (01/14/2016 09:23:53 PM) (Source: DCOM) (User: difurious)
Description: 1084WSearchUnavailable{B52D54BB-4818-4EB9-AA80-F9EACD371DF8}

Error: (01/14/2016 09:23:53 PM) (Source: DCOM) (User: difurious)
Description: 1084WSearchUnavailable{B52D54BB-4818-4EB9-AA80-F9EACD371DF8}

## Microsoft Office Sessions:

Error: (01/14/2016 09:22:06 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell)(User: difurious)
Description: Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI-2144927141

Error: (01/14/2016 09:19:44 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell)(User: difurious)
Description: Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI-2144927141

Error: (01/14/2016 07:42:35 PM) (Source: Application Error)(User: )
Description: SystemSettings.exe10.0.10240.16384559f39aeMusUpdateHandlers.dll10.0.10240.16590563ad6f2c0000005000000000002c7a822a001d14f025d5554abC:\WINDOWS\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exeC:\Windows\System32\MusUpdateHandlers.dlla7265b74-818c-498c-9ff4-d8512f85bc5cwindows.immersivecontrolpanel_6.2.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewymicrosoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel

Error: (01/14/2016 07:09:48 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-CAPI2)(User: )
Description: 
Details:
AddLegacyDriverFiles: Unable to back up image of binary Microsoft Link-Layer Discovery Protocol.

System Error:
Access is denied.

Error: (01/14/2016 06:47:23 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell)(User: difurious)
Description: Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI-2147024865

Error: (01/14/2016 06:47:23 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell)(User: difurious)
Description: Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI-2144927141

Error: (01/11/2016 10:25:41 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell)(User: difurious)
Description: Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI-2144927141

Error: (01/11/2016 10:25:41 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell)(User: difurious)
Description: Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy!App-2144927141

Error: (01/10/2016 10:14:27 PM) (Source: Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell)(User: difurious)
Description: Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI-2144927141

## CodeIntegrity Errors:

Date: 2016-01-14 21:56:21.224
  Description: Code Integrity determined that a process (\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Av\avgidsagent.exe) attempted to load \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll that did not meet the Custom 3 / Antimalware signing level requirements.

Date: 2016-01-14 21:56:21.165
  Description: Code Integrity determined that a process (\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Av\avgidsagent.exe) attempted to load \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll that did not meet the Custom 3 / Antimalware signing level requirements.

Date: 2016-01-14 21:40:11.746
  Description: Code Integrity determined that a process (\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Av\avgidsagent.exe) attempted to load \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll that did not meet the Custom 3 / Antimalware signing level requirements.

Date: 2016-01-14 21:40:11.676
  Description: Code Integrity determined that a process (\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Av\avgidsagent.exe) attempted to load \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll that did not meet the Custom 3 / Antimalware signing level requirements.

Date: 2016-01-14 21:34:05.400
  Description: Code Integrity determined that a process (\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Av\avgidsagent.exe) attempted to load \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll that did not meet the Custom 3 / Antimalware signing level requirements.

Date: 2016-01-14 21:34:05.341
  Description: Code Integrity determined that a process (\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Av\avgidsagent.exe) attempted to load \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll that did not meet the Custom 3 / Antimalware signing level requirements.

Date: 2016-01-14 21:34:04.916
  Description: Code Integrity determined that a process (\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Av\avgidsagent.exe) attempted to load \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll that did not meet the Custom 3 / Antimalware signing level requirements.

Date: 2016-01-14 21:34:04.855
  Description: Code Integrity determined that a process (\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Av\avgidsagent.exe) attempted to load \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll that did not meet the Custom 3 / Antimalware signing level requirements.

Date: 2016-01-14 19:54:06.891
  Description: Code Integrity determined that a process (\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Av\avgidsagent.exe) attempted to load \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll that did not meet the Custom 3 / Antimalware signing level requirements.

Date: 2016-01-14 19:54:06.831
  Description: Code Integrity determined that a process (\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\AVG\Av\avgidsagent.exe) attempted to load \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll that did not meet the Custom 3 / Antimalware signing level requirements.

Comment: Possible GPU error, try updating your Video driver. Also see this link  http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f299/solved-stop-0x00000101-error-advice-591847.html

Comment: There was an old bug in windows which involved muti cpu's in Vista and Server 2008..it was a windows bug, probably does not apply to you...https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/955076

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557211(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Are you over clocking the Processor?

Comment: I'm not over clocking

Comment: Did you made any changes in BIOS settings? I would recommend you to try loading the BIOS' default settings. Do you have any BIOS utilities or software utilities provided by the OEM? If you do, try uninstalling them. 
You could try reinstalling your gpu driver. Also, check the temperature of your CPU and GPU to see if they are abnormally high. You can use a software like AIDA64 for that.

Comment: I have just tried uninstalling all the GPU drivers from control panel and rebooting. But that doesn't seem to have resolved the issue. So I have tried monitoring the cpu and gpu temperature I took a picture of the temperatures when the computer froze http://imgur.com/a/E6Jsp. I uninstalled the BIOS utilities supplied by the OEM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the bios using the tool in the link seems to have solved the issue

http://www.asus.com/microsite/2014/MB/New_4th_gen_Intel_processor_compatibility/