# Computer keeps freezing in Windows 10, how can I check what could be going on?

Tags: windows-10

Sometimes it takes 10 mins, other times it can go hours without freezing, I´m kind of lost at this point.

What I did check is that the temperatures are OK, both CPU and GPU, I checked using HWMonitor.

I don't know how to get a log or error trace of sorts that tells me what is going on, I used the event viewer but cant seem to see anything logged there other than "Windows closed the wrong way" kind of message, without any info.

It's not a BSOD for what I can see, windows just freezes, no mouse interactin, no keyboard, nothing.

Any help is appreciated!.

Comment: I once encountered such a problem, where the problem was with the display adapter. If your case is the same, ensure you are using the latest driver, or add to your post the details of your video card if you want our help.

Comment: The card is an old AMD 7700, however it was working just fine for the past months, it just presented this problem now. I updated the drivers a few mins ago and still froze a few mins later.

Comment: Try to do a system restore to a time when the problem didn't exist.

Comment: 1) Is there any common app which was running when the system froze? 2) What do logs show immediately before the freeze? https://www.howtogeek.com/222730/how-to-find-out-why-your-windows-pc-crashed-or-froze/ 3) Does it occur when idle? 4) If you boot from a Linux LiveUSB https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 and let it sit, does it freeze? || Please click [edit] to answer; all data regarding the issue should be added to the question.

Comment: 1) no, no app or process in common 2) nothing, only 1 even about Windows not closing correctly 3) yes 4) hope I dont need to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 PC keeps Freezing](https://superuser.com/questions/1026494/windows-10-pc-keeps-freezing)